# $d_pf :T_p(S_1)\to T_{f(p)}(S_2)$ is a linear map for any $p\in S_1$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, plane-curves

If $f: S_1\to S_2$ is a smooth map betweentwo regular surface $S_1$ and $S_2$, then $d_pf :T_p(S_1)\to T_{f(p)}(S_2)$ is a linear map for any $p\in S_1$

I cannot prove this statement.

I think that I need to use these followings; 
$$d_pf(X_p+Y_p)=(d_pf)(X_p)+(d_pf)(Y_p)$$ and $$(d_pf)(cX_p)=c(d_pf)(X_p)$$

Comment: If you know those two facts, you're done. Those are the definition of linearity.

Comment: I know, but I cannot use these to prove it. Can you show it please? :) Dear @Neal

Comment: Don't think this has much to do with general topology or plane curves necessarily (it has with to do with spatial curves).

Comment: Do you know the definition of the tangent map $d_pf$ associated to $f$? You're given $F:X \rightarrow Y$ , and $V_p$ is a tangent space at $p$ in $X$, and $g: Y\rightarrow \mathbb R$. Then ....

Comment: I am studying differential geometry. But I want to click one more tags @Marc

Comment: I know, but I cannot express its definition properly. I know also these linearity equations. Can you help me proving this statement? @user99680

Comment: @B11b : Sure, I posted an answer; please let me know if you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a smooth map $F: X \rightarrow Y$ between manifolds, the pushforward map $DF: T_pX \rightarrow T_{F(p)}Y$ is defined ( in terms of vector fields, as in your question; as Neal said, this can also be defined in terms of curves. ) by , given a function $g: Y \rightarrow \mathbb R$: $$DF_p(X)(g):=X_p(goF) $$ ,where $X_p$ acts like a directional derivative, using the chain rule on the composition $goF$ that is, the derivation/tangent vector $X_p$ based initially at $p$ in $X$ , is sent to the derivation $X_p$ based at $F(p)$ , where it acts on the composition $goF$. Let $Y_p$ be another tangent vector based at $p$. We want to show: $$DF_p(X_p+Y_p)=DF_p(X_p)+DF_p(Y_p) $$ . But, what is $DF_p(X_p+Y_p)(g)$ ? Using the definitions, this is just : $$(X_p+Y_p)(g) $$. Now, $X_p$ and $Y_p$ are, or can be seen as, directional derivatives, and directional derivatives act linearly, so that $$ (X_p+Y_p)(g)= X_p(g)+Y_p(g)= DF_p(X_p)+DF_p(Y_p)$. A similar argument works for the second part. Can you do it?

Comment: But, I want to prove that If $f: S_1\to S_2$ is a smooth map betweentwo regular surface $S_1$ and $S_2$, then $d_pf :T_p(S_1)\to T_{f(p)}(S_2)$ is a linear map for any $p\in S_1$

Comment: I cannot see any relation between all you proved and this statement. What you said cannot be proof of this statement, i think. Sorry, or I cannot properly understand all you said.

Comment: So sorry Dear user99680. :((

Comment: No problem: I tried to show that the map between $T_p$ and $T_{F(p}$ is linear . The elemnts/vectors of $T_p$ are tangent vectors $X_p, Y_p$. To show DF is linear, you need to show $DF_p(X_p+Y_p)=DF_p(X_p)+DF_p(Y_p)$. If you give me a different definition of the tangent map, I can rewrite.

Comment: There, $F$ is a smooth map. Right? How did you use the fact $f: S_1 to S_2$ is a smooth map?

Comment: Actually, you're right; we just need $F$ to be differentiable, so that the composition $(goF)$ itself is differentiable.

Comment: Hmmm.. I am udertanding gradually:) well, how the second part works?

Comment: By the way, why defined as a manifold? Can I say "regular surface" instead of manifold?

Comment: A manifold is a sort-of generalization of a surface to higher dimensions. Just like you have local patches from the surface to $\mathbb R^2$ , for general manifolds, you have patches to $\mathbb R^3 $. So, yes, you can say it applies to surfaces, because every surface is a manifold.

Comment: Okay got it:) thanks a lot:))) everything is clear now thanks to you:))

Comment: @B11b : Glad to help.